# Javascript: How to export a SVG with embedded images to PNG?

Tags: javascript, svg, export, png

I wrote some Javascript code that allows my web application to export SVG to PNG, but the issue with this is that the embedded images aren't included in the exported PNG file.

Here is my code:

```
var svgString;

// Main download function
function download() {
    var exportResolution = 2; // TODO Changeble resolution
    var exportSVG = document.getElementById("canvas").cloneNode(true); // avoids having to reset everything afterward
    // grab its inner content BoundingBox
    var bb = document.getElementById("canvas").getBBox();
    // update its viewBox so it displays all its inner content
    exportSVG.setAttribute('viewBox', bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + ' ' + bb.width + ' ' + bb.height);
    exportSVG.setAttribute('width', bb.width);
    exportSVG.setAttribute('height', bb.height);
    exportSVG.style.fontFamily = "lato";
    exportSVG.style.background = "none"; // TODO without and with background
    svgString = getSVGString(exportSVG);
    console.log(exportSVG.getBBox().width + " / " + exportSVG.getBBox().height);
    svgStringToImage(svgString, bb.width * exportResolution, bb.height * exportResolution, 'png', save); // passes Blob and filesize String to the callback
    console.log("svg export code loaded");
}

function save(dataBlob, filesize) {
    saveAs(dataBlob, 'Example File Name'); // FileSaver.js function, TODO change to document name
}

// Below are the functions that handle actual exporting:
function getSVGString(svgNode) {
    svgNode.setAttribute('xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
    var cssStyleText = getCSSStyles(svgNode);
    appendCSS(cssStyleText, svgNode);
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svgNode);
    svgString = svgString.replace(/(\w+)?:?xlink=/g, 'xmlns:xlink='); // Fix root xlink without namespace
    svgString = svgString.replace(/NS\d+:href/g, 'xlink:href'); // Safari NS namespace fix
    return svgString;

    function getCSSStyles(parentElement) {
        var selectorTextArr = [];
        // Add Parent element Id and Classes to the list
        selectorTextArr.push('#' + parentElement.id);
        for (var c = 0; c < parentElement.classList.length; c++)
            if (!contains('.' + parentElement.classList[c], selectorTextArr))
                selectorTextArr.push('.' + parentElement.classList[c]);
        // Add Children element Ids and Classes to the list
        var nodes = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var id = nodes[i].id;
            if (!contains('#' + id, selectorTextArr))
                selectorTextArr.push('#' + id);
            var classes = nodes[i].classList;
            for (var c = 0; c < classes.length; c++)
                if (!contains('.' + classes[c], selectorTextArr))
                    selectorTextArr.push('.' + classes[c]);
        }
        // Extract CSS Rules
        var extractedCSSText = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
            var s = document.styleSheets[i];

            try {
                if (!s.cssRules) continue;
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.name !== 'SecurityError') throw e; // for Firefox
                continue;
            }
            var cssRules = s.cssRules;
            for (var r = 0; r < cssRules.length; r++) {
                if (contains(cssRules[r].selectorText, selectorTextArr))
                    extractedCSSText += cssRules[r].cssText;
            }
        }
        return extractedCSSText;

        function contains(str, arr) {
            return arr.indexOf(str) === -1 ? false : true;
        }
    }

    function appendCSS(cssText, element) {
        var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
        styleElement.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        styleElement.innerHTML = cssText;
        var refNode = element.hasChildNodes() ? element.children[0] : null;
        element.insertBefore(styleElement, refNode);
    }
}

function svgStringToImage(svgString, width, height, format, callback) {
    var format = format ? format : 'png';
    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgString))); // Convert SVG string to data URL
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            var filesize = Math.round(blob.length / 1024) + ' KB';
            if (callback) callback(blob, filesize);
        });
    };
    image.src = imgsrc;
}
```

Here's the SVG drawing in my application:
[image]

And you can see how the exported PNG file looks:
[image]

As you can see, the checkboxes (which are embedded SVG files) aren't included in the final PNG file.

What are the most common methods used to include the embedded images in this case?

Comment: convert the embedded images to data uris before you do the png conversion.

Comment: do you have a specific example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#SVG